# How do you delete a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I accidentally made a chat room. Is there anything I can do to delete it?

I created it by migrating a discussion I was having with another user in comments to chat, creating a chat room called "Discussion between Gwenn and Kyle Willey." I never really wanted to create a separate chat room, and since we've finished our conversation, it feels like a horribly irrelevant thing to have in chat.

Comment: Consider it axed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was created by the site to extend the discussion you were having. Average users cannot remove them, only moderators can. Just leave it be for now, it will be taken care of eventually or I think you can flag it for Moderator attention and post a message in it asking for it to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

As iKlsR said, only mods and SE employees can delete a room manually. Rooms can also be deleted automatically.

Per http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.